# Delphi Berlin disable function autocomplete

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-10.1-berlin

In RAD Studio, you can use `<ctrl + space>` to bring up a list of words to autocomplete a name.  However if you're doing something like this:

```
procedure TM
```

and use the shortcut, make your selection, it will generate into this:

```
procedure TMyClass;
begin
end;
```

Which seems pointless because of a few reasons, but most predominantly if you're completing a class name, it won't even compile that.  It forces you to go back, delete the begin and end tags, and then strike the end key to reach the end of the line.  Pretty bad design (but then again, they let you click past the end of line in their IDE, which again shows back design because you can't turn this 'feature' off).

Is there a way to stop their autocompleting "helpfulness"?  If this were a regular non-class method, it'd likely be fine, but given that I don't write straight procedural Delphi, it's pretty dang stupid and it kills my thought flow when I'm having to go back and delete it's attempts at being helpful.

Comment: Why not go to the options and disable what you don't want. Are you aware that the ide has options?

Comment: I am; and I've been fumbling with them for an hour without any luck in figuring out how to disable this "feature".  Hence why I asked a question.

Comment: Have you tried Tools | Options | Editor Options | Code Insight, then uncheck  `Code completion`?  Btw, there is a Help button on that tab.

Comment: Yes, and it still does what I'm trying to get it to stop doing.

Comment: Why do you invoke completion if you don't want it.

Comment: I want it more for the functionality of not having to type out long class names or search for function names.  It seems to me, like other editors I have used for a while now, that when you start typing something, you should be able to hit the down arrow a time or two to get your selection, hit it, have it finish the rest of the name for you.  Then you can type the dot operator, and a list of methods associated with that class then appears and you can select from that.  That's all I want.  Granted, I have a bad taste in my mouth about RAD studio from the get go but that's another story.

Comment: "seems to me ..."  Funnily enough I was thinking something similar the other day.  I got as far as thinking it would be interesting to see if I could write something using the ToolsAPI to do it, but not much further yet.

Comment: I usually approach this by doing it the other way. Go to the class definition, type `procedure Whatever` and hit Ctrl+Shift+C, and let the IDE write the implementation shell. (I'd never hit the issue you describe, and it took a little experimentation to figure out what you were asking.)

Comment: > *".. and use the shortcut, make your selection, it will generate into this: ..."* > Why would you select the class definition at that point? As soon as  the list pops with the class name, press Esc., and that's it. You can continue typing from where you left off.